# Query 3 tables in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables that bring information about freight, with the following structure bellow.
My problem is that it seeks equal values ​​between 2 tables, but does not compare with 3.

Join is comparing the same data between

```
    public function listarOcorrencia($pedido) {
    $this->db->select("t2.data, t3.situacao, t3.legenda, t3.cod_transportadora");
    $this->db->join('table3 t3', 't3.de = t2.ocorrencia');//return this
    $this->db->join('table1 t1', 't1.nome = t3.cod_transportadora');//and this separeted
    $this->db->from('table2 t2');//ok
    $this->db->where('t2.pedido_id', $pedido);//ok
    $this->db->order_by('t2.data', 'asc');
    
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In select function you have to app add 3 tabels required fields. For example use * in the select you get to know what is wrong